# SQL Derby get year

Tags: sql, derby

First off, I'm using Derby, which I hate, but I have to for this project.  I'm trying to pull back specific years in a very simple query and keep running into errors.  I'm hoping someone here will be able to point out what I might be doing wrong.

```
select customer, transaction, year(paymentdate) as pmtdate, amount
from paymenttable
where pmtdate like '%2012%'
```

It seems trivial, but I can't execute the above query correctly.  year(paymentdate) is returning as a date.  Any advise would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

[`Year()`](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.2/ref/rrefyearfunc.html) as defined in Derby will always return either a integer or null - it doesn't make much sense for it to do otherwise. So your statement is getting a int from that at least.

The problem usually comes from the `WHERE` clause not "finding" the `pmtdate` column in your select expression. There are two possible solutions to this:

If you need the year to be in the returned row, simply swap your `WHERE` clause for a `HAVING` one:

```
SELECT customer, transaction, YEAR(paymentdate) AS pmtdate, amount
    FROM paymenttable
    HAVING pmtdate = 2012;
```

`HAVING` technically works on groups, but effectively it works on the rows returned after grouping is done, by which time your `pmtdate` column "exists" for the engine to find. `WHERE` works on the rows right off the table, so the `YEAR()` function gets in there too late.

Alternatively, if you only need to use the year as a limiting factor in your query and it isn't needed for the results:

```
SELECT customer, transaction, paymentdate, amount
    FROM paymenttable
    WHERE YEAR(paymentdate) = 2012;
```

Comment: "*and SQL in general*" is not true. The SQL standard defines the `extract` function for this: `extract(year from some_date)`. There is no `year()` function in the SQL standard. Plus you shouldn't use `like` for integers it's for strings. the correct condition would be `year(pmtdate) = 2012`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks for the clairification - edited. I know the MySQL and MSSQL `YEAR` functions do exactly the same and have `int` return types - and had thus generalized it in my head. And while `LIKE` is indeed for strings, are there instances where it doesn't recast a (known to be) int? While I would certainly normally use `=` in this case, I try to be generous in interpreting others' examples - `'%2012%'` could just be a simple stand in for a more complex generated condition.

Answer (score 2):

doing a `like` on a `date` column makes no sense. `like` is for strings not for dates.

As the `year()` function returns an integer (not a `date)` you just have to use a proper integer comparison in your where clause:

```
select customer, transaction, paymentdate, amount
from paymenttable
where year(paymentdate) = 2012
```

You didn't say which "error" you got, but it most probably was because you can't use a column alias `as pmtdate` in the where clause. You need to reference the full expression unless you put that into a derived table:

```
select * 
from (
   select customer, transaction, year(paymentdate) as pmtdate, amount
  from paymenttable
) t
where pmtdate = 2012
```